# Couldn't encode Plus character in URL + swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, encoding

I am using a GET method in which i have to pass a email address in the URL. API expects it to be encoded. I tried with the encoding options but the '+' character couldnt be encoded.

I tried with the following code

```
let encodedEmail = emailAddressTxt.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)

let urlString = "http://www.example.com/User/GetUserDetailsByEmailAddress?EmailAddress=\(encodedEmail!)"

print(escapedString)
```

It prints http://www.example.com/User/GetUserDetailsByEmailAddress?EmailAddress=mano+1%40gmail.com

Where the '@' character is only encoded and '+' is not encoded.

Comment: you are supposed to use urlQueryAllowed for that part of the URL but the plus sign doesn't t need to be percent escaped.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately, both `CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed` and `CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed` contains `+` as **allowed**. And for historical reason, most web servers treat `+` as a replacement of whitespace (), so you need to escape `+`.

For such purpose, you may need to define your own `CharacterSet`:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let rfc3986Unreserved = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~")
}

let emailAddressText = "mano+1@gmail.com"

let encodedEmail = emailAddressText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.rfc3986Unreserved)

print(encodedEmail!) //->mano%2B1%40gmail.com
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use .urlHostAllowed character set '+' is not encoded.

Add extension to String like below

```
public func stringByAddingPercentEncodingToData() -> String? {
    let finalString = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26").replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
    return finalString
}
```

You can do something like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
let encodedEmail = emailAddressTxt.text!

        var urlString = "http://yyy.xxx.com/User/GetUserDetailsByEmailAddress?EmailAddress=\(encodedEmail)"
        urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

or

let encodedEmail = emailAddressTxt.text!

```
let urlString = "http://yyy.xxx.com/User/GetUserDetailsByEmailAddress?EmailAddress=\(encodedEmail!)"
urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)

print(escapedString)
```