# How to encode ''+' character in url string?

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

I want to encode the **`+`** character in my url string, I tried to do that this way:

```
let urlString = "www.google.com?type=c++"

let result = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

but this won't work for **`+`**.

any idea? Thanks.

**Update:**

What's more this `type=` parameter in the url is dynamic, I wouldn't do some implicite replacement on the **`+`**  character. This `type=` parameter represents a UITextField value, so there can be typed-in anything.

I'm also curious why `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` won't work in this particular case?

Comment: Can you use **urlString.replaceOccourences(of: "+", with:"")** ?

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41568692/6541007).

Comment: Please read update. I won't do replacement of characters in this case

Comment: It won't work, because `+` is perfectly valid character for `url query string`, it's `url encoded` version of `[space]`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ").inverted

if let escapedString = "www.google.com?type=c++".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) {
  print(escapedString)
}
```

Output:

> www.google.com%3Ftype%3Dc%2B%2B

Comment: Yes, your approach is well enough (not ideal), but I'm curious why `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` won't work...

Comment: That's something i can't answer, they've probably not added the `+` to that for some good reason.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

Using an Extension and add the plus to the not allowed Characters, so you can create your own characterSet and reuse it everywhere you need it. :

```
extension CharacterSet {
    
    /// Characters valid in part of a URL.
    ///
    /// This set is useful for checking for Unicode characters that need to be percent encoded before performing a validity check on individual URL components.
    static var urlAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet {
        // You can extend any character set you want
        var characters = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        characters.subtract(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+"))
        return characters
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let urlString = "www.google.com?type=c++"

let result = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlAllowedCharacters)
```

I found a list with the character sets for url encoding.
The following are useful (inverted) character sets:

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24552028/8642838

Answer (score 1):

Replace + with %2B

```
let urlString = "www.google.com?type=c++"
let newUrlString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

Comment: your approach is the last thing which I would like to do with it