# Encode a URL in UTF-8 format

Tags: ios, swift, url

I have the following query of url :

```
url_query = q=type:*&front_id:[1%20TO%206]&fq=status:[100%20TO%20400]&sort=start_datetime%20ASC,sort=status%20ASC&start=0&rows=20"
```

I want to encode this query into UTF-8 format .

I have tried :

```
let encoded_url_query = url_query!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

But the above code gives me wrong result : It gives me the following -

```
q=type%3A*&front_id%3A%5B1%2520TO%25206%5D&fq=status%3A%5B100%2520TO%2520400%5D&sort=start_datetime%2520ASC,sort=status%2520ASC&start=0&rows=20
```

**It is not encoding the '&' and '=' in the query into UTF-8 format**

I want the result to be :

```
q%3Dtype%3A%2A%26front_id%3A%5B1%2520TO%25206%5D%26fq%3Dstatus%3A%5B100%2520TO%2520400%5D%26sort%3Dstart_datetime%2520ASC%2Csort%3Dstatus%2520ASC%26start%3D0%26rows%3D20
```

Comment: Build your URL with `URLComponents` and things will work must easier.

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41561853/6541007). `.urlHostAllowed` contains `&` and `=` as allowed, which means `&` and `=` are not escaped. And there is no predefined character set for your purpose in Apple's frameworks. You may need to define your own `CharacterSet` and use `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` with it.

Comment: @rmaddy can you explain it a bit further

Comment: @OOPer it worked, thanks :)